# Efficient Storage Strategies for ERC721 with Editable Content

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, nft, erc-721, meta-data

I'm just starting to learn about smart contracts, Ethereum and NFTs. It's all new and I need your help with managing **editable NFTs**.

I want to create **a NFT with content** that is easy to **modify** while keeping things **decentralized** as much as possible. For example, I want to be able to modify these types of attributes:

"title", "description", "image1", "image2", "image3", "url1", "url2", etc.

I'm thinking of using **IPFS to store things off-chain** and update the URI for changes. But if I understand correctly, this means creating a new JSON each time?

Also, regarding the images stored in the metadata, I'd like the images to remain the property of the users even if they're no longer used, but that means creating a new NFT each time and then I can't see how to link this "image" NFT to my main NFT?

Basically, what is the best possible approach **to store/link a list of NFTs** in my main NFT, managing access rights, transfers and all that stuff?

All these questions lead me to say that I should store the data on Chain, but I have the impression that this is not generally advisable for reasons of gas and performance.

I'm fairly new to Ethereum and any simple advice on managing editable content in ERC721 contracts would be great.

Thanks for your answers